# Civimail 4.6.2 on Drupal 7.36 creating multiple drafts while editing

Tags: civimail

We recently upgraded from CiviCRM 4.5.8 to 4.6.2 and this is our first shot with the new interface.  We're just at the compose stage but what we've run into so far:

- Multiple copies of the draft appear to be created as you're editing.  In some of those copies it will say "place holder" in the Mailing Name column while others have the correct Mailing Name.
- Once you've backed out of the editor (either from a freeze as we've had with IE or you just intend to come back later to finish it up), the Status column shows "Complete" and the Scheduled/Started/Completed columns now have timestamps.  Nothing has been sent and if you click on the Report link it shows all "0" even though while editing there was a number for the estimated recipients.
- Even though the Status shows as Complete versus Not scheduled as it would back in 4.5.8, these draft mailings show up for both Mailing Status of Draft/Unscheduled as well as Complete.

At this point we've seen this from a client using Windows 7 and IE while I'm using Chrome on Linux.  Using the same Chrome/Linux combo I was able to get a mailing composed and sent using CiviCRM 4.6.2 on a WordPress site.

I just put in the define('CIVICRM_CIVIMAIL_UI_LEGACY',1); setting into the civicrm.settings.php file to get this mailing out but can revert back for some testing.

Comment: To be clear, your saying that accessing the same site from 2 browsers, the bug appears in IE but not Chrome?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the bug shows up on the Drupal site with both styles of browser (IE & Chrome) but not on the Wordpress site with the Chrome browser (haven't tried IE there yet).

Comment: (posting as answer instead)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to update to 4.6.3.

In CiviCRM 4.6.2 on Joomla 3.4.1, I experienced somewhat the same thing. After sending the mailing, the draft remained in Drafts and was marked as Completed with all the appropriate reports. So, there are two identical listings for the same mailing in each Scheduled/Sent and Drafts areas.

***Can the duplicate in Drafts be deleted or is it a the same entry as what is in the Scheduled/Sent area?***

I updated today with CiviCRM 4.6.3, and performed the same and usual process and this doesn't occur any longer.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a bit like [CRM-16251](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16251). Are you, by any chance, using smart groups? Try editing the file `CRM/Contact/BAO/GroupContactCache.php` around line 546 and changing `DROP TABLE` to  `DROP TEMPORARY TABLE`, as in [5467c9fbb](https://github.com/totten/civicrm-core/commit/5467c9fbb5dede1caacde4e4eed10e1da76b472f).